# How to get a servlet request attribute from an included one?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, nullpointerexception

I have the following code in 1 servlet:

```
dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("LoginModel");
dispatcher.include(request, response);
if ((boolean) request.getAttribute("Successful")) {}
```

and this in the 2nd servlet:

```
request.setAttribute("Successful", true);
```

However, I keep getting a `NullPointerException` on the `request.getAttribute("Successful")`

Comment: Is url-mapping `LoginModel` for 2nd servlet?

Comment: @Arvind yes it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason why your code is doing this is because your `LoginModel` servlet is not being called (BTW, have you debugged it to check?).

The `NullPointerException` happens because you're trying to cast a null reference to a `boolean` (a safe-check would resolve this, but not the call itself).

See one example, which is working properly:

**Servlet 1:**

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/serv")
public class Serv extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("serv2");
        dispatcher.include(request, response);
        if (request.getAttribute("Successful") != null
                && (boolean) request.getAttribute("Successful")) {
            System.out.println("Success!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No success!");
        }
    }
}
```

**Servlet 2:**

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/serv2")
public class Serv2 extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        request.setAttribute("Successful", true);
    }
}
```

Final result:

```
Success!
```

Comment: Hi, It appears as though that it was a catch in the second servlet that was causing the NPE, Now just got to solve why the catch is occurring!